# How to convert this java code with null condition check into Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

Recently I'm trying to convert a Java code snippet into Kotlin. I have a special need in this code to only initialize an object when some condition is met, and I don't what to get the side-effect of this initialization (getting an empty new file) if there is no need to initialize it. 
However Kotlin doesn't allow for no initialization. 
Anyone has any idea to solve this? Thanks

## Java code

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
for (...) {
    if (condition met) {
        if (fos == null) {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        }
        fos.write(something);
    }
}
```

## Kotlin code I've tried:

```
var fos: FileOutputStream?;
for (...) {
    if (condition met) {
        if (fos == null) { // compiler error: not initialized
            fos = FileOutputStream(filename);
        }
    }
    fos.write(something)
}
```

## Also this

```
var fosCreated: Boolean = false;
var fos: FileOutputStream?;
for (...) {
    if (condition met) {
        if (!fosCreated) { // compiler error: not initialized
        fos = FileOutputStream(filename);
        fosCreated = true;
    }
    fos.write(something)
}
```

Comment: Can't you just do `var fos: FileOutputStream? = null`? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes, it works :-), together with "fos?.write(something)", without "?" the compiler complains. Thank you.

Comment: ok, great. In that case I've turned it into an answer.

Comment: Depending on what happens after the code, you may also consider `lateinit var fos: FileOutputStream`

Comment: most of the time,this's bad smell to use var  in kotlin. maybe you can use val fos = list.find{condition}?.also{FileOutputStream(it.filename)}

Answer (score 2):

The problem with:

```
var fos: FileOutputStream?;
```

...is that you're not initialising it to anything. (Java would complain about an uninitialised type in the same way.)

You can trivially initialise it to null:

```
var fos: FileOutputStream? = null
```

As you discovered in the comment, you'll need to make sure you use `fos?.write()` rather than `fos.write()` to satisfy [Kotlin's null safety features](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html).